# How to create Cascade multiple Select List custom field?

Tags: jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I need to create a field as a cascade select list field like the default provided in JIRA but with slight differences. It will appear in screen as shown below:

```
FIELD NAME: <drop downlist 1> <drop downlist 2> <drop downlist 1> <drop downlist 2> <drop downlist 1> <drop downlist 2>
```

There is no parent-child relationship between dropdown list 1 and dropdown list 2. It is just repeating in three pairs as above.

Can anyone please suggest to me,

1. Which type of custom field type I should choose to create this plugin?
2. In admin configuration mode, how would I be able to configure two dropdown lists?
3. Some approach or examples which can help me to achieve this?

The actual lists are as shown below:

So if I were to keep - month list as a static and year list is configurable from the admin side, will it work if I choose to extend - `AbstractCustomFieldType<Map<String, Option>, Option>`
OR 
if I suppose to go with this - `AbstractSingleFieldType<Option>` then I am afraid it may not get fail with multiple list as the year list will have three copies of the same list and can be selectable with different values.

Any suggestions?

Thank You

Comment: again, this can be done quite easily on the client side using js

Comment: this will need to store into database too but.. is it possible through client side ?

Comment: sure, by creating a servlet on the server-side that will handle this client and will insert them to the db

Comment: updated question details. if any one can provide resolution then really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to edit this vm file according to your need.

\Atlassian\JIRA\atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\templates\plugins\fields\edit\edit-cascadingselect.vm